# Direction of Induced Electric Field in a coaxial cable?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was working through Griffith's book when I came across this problem:

An alternating current, of the form $I(t) = I_0cos(\omega t) $ flows down a long straight wire, and returns (loops back) along a coaxial cylindrical conducting tube of radius $R$.

What is the direction of the induced electric field? I think it should be radial by symmetry, but the answer seems to indicate that it is axial; and I'm having trouble working out the reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Think about a loop around the central wire, but inside the outer conductor, with its surface defining a plane perpendicular to the wire. Ampere's law tells us the induced magnetic field curls around the central wire. [Even if there were a time-dependent radial E-field it would not produce any displacement current through the loop.]

Having established that there must be a time-dependent B-field in the $\phi$ direction (cylindrical polar coordinates with the z-axis along the wire), then from Faraday's law, the curl of the E-field must also be in the $\phi$ direction. But if the curl of E is in the $\phi$ direction then the E-field itself must be in the z-direction along the axis of the wire.